# ul is not getting correct height

Tags: html, css

The problem is  is not getting the height of it's children. So footer is overlapping to the ul.

I want the ul to be finished first and then load the footer.

```
<ul>
    <li>First Slide</li>
    <li>Second Slide</li>
    <li>Third Slide Third Slide Third Slide Third Slide Third Slide Third Slide Third slide Third slide Third slide Third slide Third slide  </li>
</ul>
<section class="footer">some weird content</section>
```

JSfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/Kct8m/1/

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/Kct8m/2/ ?

Comment: Add min-height to the ul , to avoid the overlapping.

Comment: How can I know the actual min-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because your `li` class is setting `position:absolute;` to the list items.

Change it to `position:relative;`.

When you set position to absolute, it goes to another level in the page, so it stops interfering with the other page's elements. Position relative keeps the element on the same level as the others, so it still affects every other element.

**EDIT**

The only way would be through Javascript. Remove the `height: 100%` from the li, and do something like:

```
function setUlSize() {
    var h = 0;
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul1"); //Or whatever ul id
    for(var i=0; i<ul.children.length; i++) {
        if(h < ul.children[i].offsetHeight)
            h = ul.children[i].offsetHeight;
    }
    ul.style.height = h + "px";
}

window.onresize = setUlSize;
setUlSize();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kct8m/7/

Comment: Sorry I can't keep it to relative.It needs to be absolute. I am making a slider left to right and right to left so for that reason I am keeping li as absolute

Comment: See the eddited answer. You can't have a `position: absolute` element to affect another element.

Comment: I understand but the problem this is going to be a slider and I need to position the li as absolute.

Comment: You can add min-height to the ul in that case. demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Kct8m/4/

Comment: Sound a better solution/answer.Thanks mate.I will implement it.

Answer (score 1):

If Im right then...Please explain what you mean by Slide1 etc. Maybe Im wrong,If so let me know to update my answer!

http://jsfiddle.net/Kct8m/5/

Added Classes to the Li's

```
<li class="first">First Slide</li>
    <li class="second">Second Slide</li>
    <li class="third">Third Slide Third Slide Third Slide Third Slide Third Slide Third Slide Third slide  </li>
```

and added that to the CSS

```
.first{
    position: relative;
    margin-top:0;
}

.second {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.third {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

In case that you want them to slide(marquee)

http://jsfiddle.net/Kct8m/8/

Note:i used a plugin "http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin"

```
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>

<ul> 
    <div class="marquee"><li class="first">First Slide</li></div>
    <div class="marquee"> <li class="second">Second Slide</li></div>
    <div class="marquee"> <li class="third">Third Slide Third Slide Third Slide Third Slide Third Slide Third Slide Third slide  </li></div>
    </div>
</ul>
<section class="footer">some weird content</section>
```

you will also need the jquery file

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`Javascript` used :

```
$('.marquee').marquee()
```

and `CSS` added (you can customize the content however you want)

```
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;

}
```

Let me know if this work for you.

Comment: slide 1 slide 2 and slide 3 will come in a single line.Slide 1 will have left -100% slide 2 center and slide 3 will have right 100%.It will be a horizontal slider.

Comment: Ow okay i didnt know :/

Answer (score 0):

if you can't make the `li` position `relative`. Then another option is:

Assign min-height to the `ul`

```
ul {
border: 1px solid red;
min-height: 30px; // this depends on your li height
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It can't be fixed height.Does it need to calculate the min-height via jquery?